# Docker - When does /etc/hosts gets created or updated inside container?

Tags: docker

When docker container starts, does it gets /etc/hosts file from the image it got created from and then update it with the dynamic IP/hostname assigned to this container?

Assuming container is getting started with this simple command and no special arguments are provided:

```
docker run imageid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

`/etc/hosts` exists temporarily in the image at each layer creation.
It needs to be flexible as containers are designed to be ephemeral.

### Detail

I've done a small test with the following dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN cat /etc/hosts
```

Here is the build result :

```sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> fb52e22af1b0
Step 2/2 : RUN cat /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in ad21775fc2be
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      ad21775fc2be
Removing intermediate container ad21775fc2be
 ---> 9479add5fe39
Successfully built 9479add5fe39
```

As you can see, we are able to show `etc/hosts` content.
Temp Container id is informed.

When I run an instance of this docker image:

```sh
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      5446c52a3dee
```

That file changed with runtime container id.

For more information on layers of a container :

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

#### EDIT

`docker save` experience by @david-maze shows well that it is not stored permanently inside images :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69313033/16762357

Answer (score 4):

At least in one simple image, `/etc/hosts` does *not* exist in the image; Docker synthesizes it from scratch every time it runs a container.

Arguably the simplest useful image is [`busybox`](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox), which contains the statically-linked [BusyBox](https://busybox.net) tool set and nothing else.  Its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/blob/6166a8226f7213354cc1b743477c1eabc0cb00e0/stable/uclibc/Dockerfile) is very simple, just `ADD`ing a tar file to an empty `FROM scratch` base.  If you run a container, you can see that `/etc/hosts` exists inside the container:

```sh
docker run --rm busybox cat /etc/hosts
```

But we can also dig inside the image.  Since this image is so tiny, it's straightforward.

```sh
docker save -o busybox-image.tar busybox
tar xf busybox-image.tar
ls
# there is a single layer directory with a very long name
cd 4775639832413f9c8c12a59a371ed1c5ae79cb5d743bb81266209c0620c4bf5b
mkdir layer
cd layer
# unpack the layer contents
tar xf ../layer.tar
ls ./etc
```

You can see that the image contains user-related files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, but not network-related files like `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/resolv.conf`.

The important thing this means is that you cannot embed environment-specific network information into a Docker image; you cannot include an `/etc/hosts` file because Docker will overwrite it when the container runs.  It will honor the host's DNS settings, and if your environment has some local host names, setting up a DNS server like dnsmasq or BIND (or using a cloud-hosted option like Amazon's Route 53) will be more maintainable than trying to keep hosts files in sync.